# Writing regular expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, regular-expressions

So here's the problem: Let $Σ =\{a, b, c\}$. Write a regular expression for the set of all strings in $Σ^∗$ such that the sum of the number of $a$’s and $b$’s in the string is at most two. Thus the string can have an $a$ and a $b$ but cannot have two $a$’s and a $b$, for example.

And here's what I've come up with: $(a \cup b) \cup c^*$. This way, it's not possible to have more than two $a$'s and $b$'s in the string. Did I solve the problem correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know exactly about your notation used. But something like this should work: c*[ab]c*[ab]c*

Comment: @LorenoHeer The U is the Union operator and the * is the Kleene star. Could you rewrite your answer in that notation?

Comment: $c^* \{a,b\} c^* \{a,b\} c^*$

Comment: @LorenoHeer Thank you so much!!

Comment: Note that it is not enough to write a regular expression whose results are all in the set (which you have done in this question). You also need, for every element of the set, a way to generate it from your expression. So if you have a string in the set, such as $cba,$ that doesn't match your expression, you do not have the correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to split into cases:

- At most 0 $a$ or $b$: $c^*$
- At most 1 $a$ or $b$: $c^* (a \mid b) c^*$
- At most 2 $a$ or $b$: $c^* (a \mid b) c^* (a \mid b) c^*$

The union of the three cases gives what you want.

Another way is to write $c^* (a \mid b \mid \epsilon) c^* (a \mid b \mid \epsilon) c^*$ (there are two $a$, $b$, or nothing in a sea of $c$s).